# Flask python is truncating youtube link

Tags: python, flask

I have been trying to create an API using Flask that takes a YouTube link as input. I am using the `path` URL converter. The main issue I am facing is that when I give YouTube URL as input to flask API, it truncates the link as following:

- Input: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYeWemghBxI`
- Output: `https://www.youtube.com/watch`

Is there any way to get full url?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
from pprint import pprint

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/YT/<path:yt_link>')
def index(yt_link):
    return str(yt_link)
```

Comment: Post your code as formatted text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry. Just give me a minute @KlausD.

Answer (score 1):

Send your link as url encoded. Then decode it inside `flask` code.

For example:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYeWemghBxI > encode > https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DqYeWemghBxI`

Then in flask

`https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DqYeWemghBxI > decode > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYeWemghBxI`

Comment: Hi @itzMEonTV.  I am copying the link and pasting it into my browser. Isn't there any way to just pass it as input as it is? If I just want the simple YT link to be used instead of encoding or decoding?

Comment: If you are copy pasting, can you try changing `?` to `%3F` inside the link

Comment: Multiple quetsion marks are allowed in url. But may not be expected query string values. Here `?v` means `v` is another query string

Comment: I can try it. Will let you know in a while.